# React Bootstrap dropdown menu styling problem

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have created a bootstrap dropdown menu in my react application.
The dropdown code is looks like this.

```js
<Dropdown className="drop">
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu className="dropMenu">
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Here are the css styles I have applied for this.

```css
.drop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 112px 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.drop:hover .dropMenu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But when I hover over on the button It shows a something like this.
[image: Imge of the UI]

How Can i get these items as a list.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could not get any of the recommended solutions to work. This did however:

```js
<Dropdown as={ButtonGroup}>
  <Dropdown.Toggle className="button_basics"> Sort</Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">By Price Low to High</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">By Price High to Low</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">By Year Low to High</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="4">By Year High to Low</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Of note, the custom class `.button_basics` uses **`!important`**

Answer (score 0):

In your last css class you will add two properties.. display:flex and flex-direction:column your final result will be like this..

```
.drop:hover .dropMenu {
  display:flex
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

From Bootstrap doc:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/